# How do I stop a task I created with client.loop.create_task(function) in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to add some functionality to a discord bot where I use a command to start a looping process which is working fine, but now I want to add the ability to stop this loop.

How do I stop/cancel a loop that I started with client.loop.create_task(name of function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tasks contain an attribute called [`cancel()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel), here is an example on how to use it:

```
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

async def SomeTask():
    while True:
        print("Test") # Prints 'Test' for testing purposes
        await asyncio.sleep(10) # Task gets executed every 10 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    task = client.loop.create_task(SomeTask()) # Starts the task
    await asyncio.sleep(5) # Waits 5 seconds then cancels the task
    task.cancel()

client.run("your bot token")
```

Comment: Thank you! The only thing I am still confused about is, how can I pass the "task" return value between different functions?

I'm trying to have two commands, one /on and one /off command so I think I need to pass the task reference between them.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works with discord py but could I declare the task variable outside and just pass it into both commands as an argument?

Comment: Declare it globally and access it in that way.